# Minimum of empty set in $\infty$ why is that?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, maxima-minima, supremum-and-infimum

According to a definition a minimum in a set is the smallest number in it.

My professor claimed: the minimum in empty set in $\infty$ why is that? $\infty$ isn't even a member of the empty set which contradicts the definition, plus it's will make more sense to me if it's $- \infty$

Comment: Your professor likely meant to refer to the infimum, rather than the minimum.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I am sure it's the minimum, we were talking about the shortest path between 2 vertices in graphs, in case there is no such path he said we can consider it as an empty set and then the answer is -infty

Comment: Then your professor is simply wrong; the minimum of a set must be in the set, whereas the infimum is not. However they are similar notions which is why I can see he would mix them up.

Comment: Related, and very relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951490/when-indexing-set-is-empty-how-come-the-union-of-an-indexed-family-of-subsets-o/1952303#1952303

Comment: Besides some good answers, here is an important intuition for the concept of graph distance in your comment. Given two vertices $v,w$ in a graph, let's define the distance to be the **supremum** of all real numbers $L$ such that for any path which starts at $v$, if you travel along that path and stop at path length $L$, you will not ever have encountered $w$. If some path exists from $v$ to $w$, this agrees with the distance in your comment. If no path exists from $v$ to $w$, the set of all $\{L\}$ is unbounded, and we shall agree to say that the supremum of an unbounded set is $\infty$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer then what's the minimum and infimum in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have noted, the minimum and maximum of the $\emptyset$ are undefined, since a minimum or maximum must belong to the set, but the infimum and supremum are well-defined.

The infimum of a set is the greatest lower bound.  That is, it is the largest number such that no member of the set is smaller than it.  Now if we take any real number $x$, it is surely true that no member of $\emptyset$ is smaller than $x$.  What is the largest $x$?  Well, there's no largest real number, so $\infty$ is a sensible agreement.

Similarly, the supremum of $\emptyset$ is $-\infty$.

Comment: You should probably also mention that the minimum of an empty set is "undefined", as that is what the OP asks.

Comment: @Kaind Okay, I'll add that.

Comment: I think it should also be made very clear that $\emptyset$ is being considered here as a subset of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

As you've written it, your professor is wrong.

However, there is a similar (but definitely different) notion of a greatest lower bound, also called an infimum. This value is defined as the largest value that has no set element larger than it. For an empty set, the greatest lower bound must be $\infty$.

Comment: Looks like another answer got posted as I was typing mine! Perhaps it is not so bad to see some agreement among people posting answers.

Answer (score 2):

Conventionally, the sum ($\displaystyle\sum$) of no term is $0$ and the product ($\displaystyle\prod$) of no factor is $1$. This way, the result remains coherent if you append an element. $0$ is neutral for addition, $1$ neutral for multiplication.

The same holds with the minimum: the minimum of no term must be plus infinity, so that if you append an element, the new minimum is that element. $\infty$ is neutral for the minimum.

---

Similarly, the union of no set should be defined as the empty set, and the intersection of no set, as the universe.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the empty set $\emptyset\subset \mathbb R$ as a subset of $\mathbb R$.

Every real number $r\in \mathbb R$ is a lower bound of $\emptyset$ and this is because there is no $x\in \emptyset$ such that $x\lt r$. So the set of all lower bounds of $\emptyset$ is $\mathbb R$.

So $\inf \emptyset=\sup \mathbb R=\infty$, where $\infty$ is not a real number rather it's just a symbol to show that $\mathbb R$ is unbounded above.

Using the same arguments, mutatis mutandis, for upper bounds, you will get $\sup \emptyset =\inf \mathbb R=-\infty$.

Answer (score -1):

You are right, the definition doesn't apply to the empty set. What your professor should have said is that for the empty set it's defined separately as $\infty$.

Why is this a sensitive definition?

You have some properties that you would like to remain true in the case of the empty set.

For example, if $A \subseteq B$ then $\min A \ge \min B$. That's easy to prove for non-empty sets, so you would like to define it for the empty set so this remains true.

But $\emptyset \subseteq B$ for all subsets $B$, so you'll need $\min \emptyset \ge \min B$ for all subsets $B$. In particular if $B=\{x\}$, $\min \emptyset \ge x$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Obviously there's no such real number and this clearly motivates the defintion $\min \emptyset = \infty$.

Other properties involving union, intersection or complement of sets also can be used to motivate this definition and in general all works very nice with this definition.

Note: For subsets of $\mathbb R$ in general one should talk about the infimum, not the minimum, since not all sets have a least element.